# String differ at index 0 C#

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I'm running my specflow test. Which is failing at my 'Then' step. i'm not sure why this exception is happening. My code hasn't got any exceptions and i believe my 'Then' step has been implemented correctly.

My 'Then' step is coded so it looks for a specific file path then validates the data from the file path with my expected data.

Exception

```
Message:   Expected string length 21 but was 942. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "6677,6677_6677,3001,6"
  But was:  "----- Executing Environment setup script - /orabin/app/oracle..."
  -----------^
```

Code:

```
    [Given(@"Inventory interface is generated")]
    public void GivenInventoryInterfaceIsGenerated()
    {

        Row TestData = Common.Common.ReadDataFromCSV("Inventory");
        ScenarioContext.Current["Inventory"] = TestData;
        new ConvertToCSV().CreateInterfaceData(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InventoryDatFile"], TestData["Inventory"]);
    }


    [Given("I Loaded LifeCycle Measurement in domain for the (.*)")]
    public void GivenLifecyclestatusIsLoaded(string LifeCycleStatus)
    {
        Row TestData = Common.Common.ReadDataFromCSV("Foundation");

        new ConvertToCSV().CreateInterfaceData(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[LifeCycleStatus + "lifecyclestatusCSVFileName"],
            TestData["lifecyclestatus"]);
    }

    [When(@"Inventory batch is executed")]
    public void InventoryBatchIsExecuted()
    {
        Row TestData = (Row)ScenarioContext.Current["Inventory"];
        Common.LinuxCommandExecutor
            .RunLinuxcommand(TestData["InventoryCommands"].ToString());

    }

    [Then(@"Transfer out measure should be generated (.*)")]

    public void ValidateInventoryMeasurement(string lifecyclestatus)

    {
        var Path = "irm_pgfw_trntmf_fcvt.csv.ovr";
        const string processFilePath = "/orabin/app/oracle/product/asos/inputs/ff/ff/actuals/";
        var actual = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor
                           .RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath} {Path}");

        var expected = "6677,6677_6677,3001,6";

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

Comment: The file does not contain what you expect it to.

Comment: `"cat {processFilePath} {Path}"` is suspicious - did you perhaps intend to use `Path.Combine`?

Comment: The message is assert error. I believe, The line`var actual = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor
                           .RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath} {Path}")`  is returning the process logs instead of returning expected. If the expected output is part of one line from multi-line output response then you should check the contains instead of equal.

Comment: @DaisyShipton if i used path.combine. How would it work with my example?

Comment: @user1672994 multi-line output response then you should check the contains instead of equal. This is correct. In the 'actuals' there will be multiple outputs that will be generated. 'irm_pgfw_trntmf_fcvt.csv.ovr' will just be one of the files from this long list generated

Comment: Then write a logic which works on combination -- first check the name of the file in the output response, second check the expected output in response before the log of another files start.

Comment: You'd combine the two strings into a single path, and cat that instead. But it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do at the moment.

Comment: @DaisyShipton The reason they're separate is i want to combine multi file paths with the processFilePath. But i want to test whether one is working so far.

Comment: @JOpenDock: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that. At the moment, that command will print out the content of two separate files: "/orabin/app/oracle/product/asos/inputs/ff/ff/actuals/" and "irm_pgfw_trntmf_fcvt.csv.ovr".

Comment: @DaisyShipton Ok so : "/orabin/app/oracle/product/asos/inputs/ff/ff/actuals/" is the path but then this will be the file that it needs to look for and cat irm_pgfw_trntmf_fcvt.csv.ovr. So within the 'actuals' there will be over 100 files. and it needs to look for a specific file to cat.

Comment: Right, so the file you actually want to cat is `/orabin/app/oracle/product/asos/inputs/ff/ff/actuals/irm_pgfw_trntmf_fcvt.csv.ovr`, right? So that's what `Path.Combine(processFilePath, path)`; would give you (after you renamed your `Path` variable to `path` to make it more idiomatic and avoid the naming collision you'd otherwise have)

Comment: So how would path.combine work with my code above?